# LINQ filter fields that starts with a particular integer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to filter fields that starts with a particular `integer` or list of `integers`. For example, When I enter an integer (`ex: 1`), the query should return `1, 10, 119, 1187, 1098.`

The following `query` gives me all the `Schools` that has an `Id` of `1`. However, I need to modify it so it returns `1, 10, 119, 1187, 1098.`

```
return await _dbContext.Schools.Where(c => c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(schoolId)).Take(5).ToListAsync() ;
```

Comment: `Where(c => c.Id.ToString().StartsWith(schoolId)))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, assuming:

1. `Id` is an int
2. `schoolId` is a string

```cs
return await _dbContext
   .Schools
   .Where(c => c.Id.ToString().StartsWith(schoolId)).Take(5).ToListAsync();
```